# CDN setup without nameserver AND cname manipulation

Tags: cdn, nameserver, cname

Is it possible? Does somebody know, how is it technically possible to setup a CDN without nameserver and cname manipulation?

Comment: What do you mean "without nameserver and cname manipulation?"   Do you mean that you don't want to change NS or CNAME DNS entries?   Are you open to changing A records?   CDNs use DNS tricks to route traffic to the closest edge node, so there is no way to use them without allowing some sort of DNS changes.

Comment: i'm comfortable with both of `dns` and `cname`, no prob - just was asked by a client, is there a kind of such simple possibility to setup a CDN, like to input domain name, and the CDN provider does the rest...

Comment: Your website could resolve to one IP that is anycasted (so hopefully the closer endpoint would answer requests). Or it can resolve to different IPs because the authoritative nameservers would have some logic to reply differently based on the source, and with the help of the Client Subnet EDNS option. This means "magic" in the implementation but the content of the zone would be simple and no CNAMEs nor NS changes. So you will need to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

***Not supported by all Registrars***

If you want the ability to create additional sites or content delivery networks without having to edit any DNS entries then you can adopt a wildcard setup. Sadly not all registrars allow you to do this but a example of a wild card A record looks like this: `*.cdn`.

***Virtual Host***

This allows you to create sites, apps and content delivery networks by just editing the virtual host on your server, for example `*.cdn.example.com` becomes `uniquestring.cdn.example.com`, this is how Rackspace, Azure and Amazon issue CDN for their customers.

***Amazon Route 53***

If your current domain registrar does not allow wildcards then take a look at [Amazon Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Support_for_wildcard_entries)

Comment: Wildcards create more problems than solutions (and even more so with DNSSEC), specially in the hand of beginners, so when possible it is better to try not using them.

Comment: Doesn't make it a invalid solution...

Comment: I never said it is invalid. I said that wildcards in the hands of beginners are dangerous so it is not a recommended one, but it is one among others, yes...